# Problem uploading django project to heroku: Configuring Postgres

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Django application to Heroku, but the heroku returns the message when i run the migrate command on the heroku bash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 82, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres://baz" to address: Name or service not known
```

I think is something wrong with my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),                      
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

is that right? What do i must do to configure this?

Comment: yes i run from the same root directory where the requirements.txt is

Comment: There's a `requirements.txt` file in your screenshot, but that doesn't mean it's _tracked_. Is this file committed to your repository and included in whatever branch you're trying to deploy?